Корректна ли подстановка домена в Cookies при использовании общего сервиса авторизации для РАЗНЫХ доменов?
Меня давно распирает сделать общий сервис авторизации для нескольких сайтов и наконец-то добрались руки до реализации. В процессе я столкнулся с одним моментом, проекты располагаются на разных доменах (не поддоменах, а именно доменах). Я понимаю, что установить кукис для нескольких доменов за раз нельзя.
Однако, мне пришла вот такая идея, и вопрос в том, насколько она бредовая:
При авторизации получать из запроса или из его тела нужный domain и подставлять его в куки?
response.set_cookie(
            key="Authorization",
            value=token,
            httponly=True,
            max_age=settings.access_token_expire,
            domain=".site.ru" или "othersite.ru"
        )


Не получится так сделать. Это очень серьезная уязвимость и ее давным давно закрыли. Решение - отправить токен на фронтенд и оттуда создать токен.
